# Esconder o teclado

Tags: java, android

Assim que o usuário clica em um dos `EditText` do meu aplicativo Android, o teclado aparece, porém, não some quando termina de digitar e clica fora dele.

Gostaria de saber qual método seria adequado, sabendo que possuo 3 `EditText`.

Já tentei utilizar todos os métodos a seguir, porém nenhum com sucesso:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Edit.: O código da classe está [aqui](http://pastebin.com/YaurxZkM).

A linha de código correspondente ao erro após a alteração é:

```
editRed.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
```

Comment: O link está quebrado, você poderia para melhor suportar a comunidade, inserir o código no contexto?! isso pode ajudar muitas outras pessoas também.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Acredito que clicar fora do EditText não vai fazer o teclado virtual desaparecer. Você precisa implementar um listener que esconde o teclado quando você clica fora dele (isto é, quando o EditText perde o foco). Por exemplo:

```
    searchEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
        {
            if (false == hasFocus) {
                ((InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                        searchEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: searchEditText seria o que então?

Comment: Uma referência ao seu EditText, por exemplo: `EditText searchEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);` o nome é só um exemplo.

Comment: Ah sim, certo, e o context?

Comment: O `context` pode ser removido, eu peguei de um exemplo no link que você citou. Use `this.getSystemService()` por exemplo.

Comment: Me refiro ao "context.getSystemService".

Comment: Corrigi o comentário.

Comment: Acredito que você possa trocar `searchEditText.getWindowToken()` por `((EditText)v).getWindowToken()`, experimente.

Comment: Ao trocar "context" por "this", surgiu o erro "The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){}".

Comment: Ah sim. Foi mal. Faça assim: `SuaAtividade.this.getSystemService(` ou talvez apenas remova o `this` que deve funcionar.

Comment: Criei um listener para cada um dos Edit, fiz as alterações necessárias, mas na hora do teste deu NullPointerException. Veja: http://pastebin.com/PAvdRXNk

Comment: Inclua o seu `Calculator.java` na pergunta e informe pra gente qual é a linha 50, que é onde está dando o erro.

Comment: Editado. Peço desculpas pela demora, não pude entrar no computador desde ontem.

Comment: Suas variáveis `editRed`, `editGreen`, `editBlue` não estão inicializadas. Antes dessa linha e depois de `setContentView()` você deve incluir três linhas segundo este exemplo: `editRed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtRed);`. Mova as linhas que você tem em `getCode()`, lá não é o local correto para inicializar essas variáveis.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado amigo, salvou aqui.!!!

Answer (score 2):

Método utilitário que uso para fazer isso:

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Context context, View editText) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

também tive este problema e resolvi setando o RelativeLayout com um id e utilizando este código:

```
Relativo.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                        Relativo.getWindowToken(), 0);
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Há duas formas para fazer o teclado desaparecer:

**1ª Forma**

> - torne ativo o EditText ao qual deseja que o teclado desapereça após o comando ;
> - pesquise o **Attribute imeOptions**;
> - abra o leque de options clicando na seta da esquerda;
> - selecione a **opção actionDone para TRUE**
> - salve a alteração e execute.

**2ª Forma**

> - selecione a aba **activity_main.xml**;
> - ative a visualização da aba CODE;
> - insira o texto **android:imeOptions="actionDone"** em uma linha da tag  na qual deseje que o teclado se feche.
> - salve a alteração e execute.

Answer (score -1):

Voce pode colocar a tela inteira dentro de um *GestureDetector*

```
new Scaffold(
 body: new GestureDetector(
   onTap: () {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
  },
 child: Container()
 )
)
```